# How to enlarge image in iframe on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I don't know the best way to enlarge image in my iframe. Here's my code.

```
 <table id="offer">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
<td class="frame"><iframe id="content1" name="content1" src="/uploads/images/1.jpg"    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></td>
<td class="o1">
<div class="p2"><a href="/uploads/images/1.jpg" target="content1"><img src="/uploads/images/1.jpg" alt="" width="320" height="173" /></a></div>
</td>
<td class="o2">
<div class="p3"><a href="/uploads/images/2.jpg" target="content1"><img src="/uploads/images/2.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
</td>
<td class="o3">
<div class="p4"><a href="/uploads/images/3.jpg" target="content1"><img src="/uploads/images/3.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

For now it works like that: when I click on smaller image(classes p1, p2, p3) it loads this image into iframe.
But the second step, which I can't make is to enlarge this loaded image by clicking it.
Is there an easy way to do it? Help pls.

Comment: do you have jsfiddle we could see for this?

Comment: It's sth like that. But I don't know how to add images in fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/v1f0s7ac/

Comment: You could use the `transform : scale(1.5);` to do this, but it will alter your image so my advice to you is to first load your image, apply a `scale(0.5)` and then increase on click to `scale(1)`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are trying to do this with an iframe?  What exactly are you trying to create here?  There may be a better option for how to execute this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice overflow: hidden in my css. But even if I scale my image by transform, how to connect it with click event?

Comment: Casey - I'm trying to make gallery for products, in fact iframe is not necessary if U know better solution. Only thing is that smaller images are loaded form page to larger box. I could't find in web a gallery that support this.